# The meaning of the this function

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering

I know the C, but i am new to cpp and to the reverse engineering. I began to read some viruses. In one of them i met this kind of structure.

```
void __thiscall CBigInt(CBigInt *this)

{
  int local_8;

  *(undefined4 *)this = 1;
  local_8 = 0;
  while (local_8 < 0x23) {
    *(undefined4 *)(this + local_8 * 4 + 4) = 0;
    local_8 = local_8 + 1;
  }
  return;
}
```

I could export all undefined types, and they are typedef unsigned char   undefined;

```
typedef unsigned char    byte;
typedef unsigned char    dwfenc;
typedef unsigned int    dword;
typedef long long    longlong;
typedef unsigned char    uchar;
typedef unsigned int    uint;
typedef unsigned long    ulong;
typedef unsigned long long    ulonglong;
typedef unsigned char    undefined1;
typedef unsigned short    undefined2;
typedef unsigned int    undefined3;
typedef unsigned int    undefined4;
typedef unsigned long long    undefined5;
typedef unsigned long long    undefined6;
typedef unsigned long long    undefined7;
typedef unsigned long long    undefined8;
typedef unsigned short    ushort;
typedef unsigned short    word;
typedef struct __class_type_info __class_type_info, *P__class_type_info;
```

Now i just want to create a variable like below:

```
int main()
{
    CBigInt local_3fc [144];
    return 0;
}
```

However i got an error, even without it, i just dont understant declaration of the function. Could you explain it?

Comment: Is the function `CBigInt` defined at global scope or inside the definition of a `class` or `struct`? Is this C or C++ code? I am asking because in C++, the `this` pointer is implicit and is normally not declared explicitlly.

Comment: In actual C++ code, that function would be an ordinary constructor. This looks like straight decompiled code. (And C code at that, where you can actually use `this` as a variable name, even though the original source was C++.)

Comment: That is C++ code. I just dont understand how the type can be the function itself? And how ```void __thiscall CBigInt(CBigInt *this)``` could even work?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Unfortunately i did not know, if its in class or struct. But its definately cpp code. I have just an elf file, and while reversing it with ghidra i could get this function,

Comment: "I just dont understand how the type can be the function itself?" - The `this` pointer (which is normally implicit in C++) points to the instance of the class. It does not point to a function. In C++, the function names of a constructor have the same name as the class name.

Comment: Thanks, i think i got it =)